# How do I list all the files in git?

Tags: git

```
git show --name-only
```

does what i want, but there's a header, which my script then mangles

```
git show --name-only | head -n 5
```

Shows the bit i don't want.

```
git show --name-only | tail -n +7
```

Nails it.

Surely there is a better way?

Specifically, I want the names (and paths) of all the files which exist and are version controlled in the current state of my repository.

Comment: Do you want to list all the files, or the files in the latest commit? `git show` by default lists all the files modified in the latest commit, not all the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want:

`git ls-files`

Comment: With `-r` to show files in sub directories. Should be `git ls-files -r HEAD`.

Comment: `ls-files` lists all files. I think `git show` by default lists the files modified in the latest commit.

Answer (score 1):

First a clarification `git show` will - without any flags - list the files of the **latest commit**, not of all added files.

You can use the `--pretty=oneliner` to ensure only the first line will contain information. So by using

```
git show --name-only --pretty=oneline | tail -n +2
```

You make sure you will never (for future versions) cut away real information.

In case you want a list of all files under subversioning, you should use `git ls-files` as answered by @DavidHoelzer.